# Why are other audio devices unusable?

Tags: audio, windows-8.1

Some time ago, all audio devices on my computer except one became unusable. The one that works is an old USB sound card. The motherboard's onboard audio has stopped working, a new USB sound card has the same issue, and even audio devices connected to a new USB Bluetooth dongle I recently installed have the same issue. Everything reports as enabled, suitable drivers, and working properly. Unplugging the old, working USB sound card doesn't restore functionality to anything else; my computer then simply lacks a functioning audio device.

Affected devices have no audio level readout in the list of sound devices:

[image: initial]

Opening the device's properties and looking at the "levels" tab shows this kind of blank window:

[image: levels]

Attempting to use an available microphone on such a device for recording in Audacity produces an error:

> Error opening recording device.
>
> Error code: -9999 Unanticipated host error.

There's [a thread on answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/microphone-levels-in-properties-is-blank/e4c2ba0f-5dc6-47fb-bbf4-10b436463532) describing what appears to be a similar issue, with the same blank window for sound levels, but the only suggested fix is essentially a fresh Windows installation, which I am hoping to avoid.

What exactly has broken and how do I fix it?

Comment: Try SFC and DISM to repair system files: https://www.bitrecover.com/blog/repairing-windows-files-sfc-dism-commands/ . If that doesn't work, then *make a disk image* before trying reinstallation, keeping your current files and setup. That said, 8.1 end-of-life approaches,  so consider migrating to Windows 10 (or 11, if the PC is capable), or an alternate OS such as Linux. You can try Ubuntu without installing it or modifying *anything* on your PC.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - Those both give errors. I suppose I'll have to make peace with the nuclear option.

Comment: With Windows 10, reinstallation *while keeping files* has worked for me, on occasion, without need to reinstall *applications* and without data loss. That said, make a disk image before trying this on Windows 8, in particular. Again, consider going to a newer OS, whether Windows or Linux.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - That's "Refresh your PC without affecting your files" in 8.1, right? I don't think I have the wherewithal to create and restore a disk image; it'll either work or need a full reset. =\

Comment: Making a disk image is trivial. All that is needed is storage to hold as much space as is actually used; if you have a 500 GB HDD, and only 150 GB are used, then you need a device such as a USB HDD or flash drive of 150 GB. For Windows, there are numerous free applications to save that image, such as Macrium Reflect and EaseUS Todo Backup.